# Quotient of two ideals equality

Tags: ring-theory

I was following a sequence of ring isomorphisms, sorry about that but I cannot figure out why in the last step we have:

$ (x^2+ 1, 1+x) / (1+x) = ( 2)  $   in the ring $ \mathbb{Z} [X] / (1+x) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that:

$$x^2 + 1 = x(x+1) - x + 1 = x(x+1) - (x+1) + 2$$

Thus in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+1)$ we have that $x^2 + 1 = 2$, so $(x^2 + 1) + I = 2 + I$, where $I = \langle 1+x \rangle$

Comment: Thanks. So when i consider the map $ \Phi: \mathbb{Z}  [X] / (X+1) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \: \: $\newline $ \pi (P) \mapsto \pi ( P(-1))   $  then  we would get $ \Phi( (x^2 + 1) + (x+1))  = \Phi( (2) + (1+x))  = (2) $ hence $  \mathbb{Z}  [X] / (X+1) \cong  \mathbb{Z} / (2) $ if i am not mistaken